# showing an element of $E''$ is actually in $E$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space, and let $E'$ denote its dual space.  Suppose I define a functional $f:E'\to\mathbb{C}$ and claim that it is actually in the image of the canonical embedding $E\hookrightarrow E''$.

This has been tossed around, but I just want to double check:

Is it sufficient to check that it is continuous with respect to the $w^*$-topology on $E'$?

It seems to me that if I had an element of $E''$, not in $E$, that were continuous with respect to the $w^{*}$-topology on $E'$, that this would force the weak star topology to have "extra" open sets, in the sense of being the weakest topology such that all the seminorms $p_{\varphi}$ defined by

$$p_{\varphi}(F) = F(\varphi)$$

are continuous.  Is my logic correct, or is there more to check here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need only check continuity in the weak$^*$-topology.  The continuous dual of $E'$ with the weak$^*$-topology consists solely of the evaluation functionals. Hence if $f$ is weak$^*$-continuous, then it is evaluation by some $x\in E$.

Comment: Thanks!  I am assuming you mean that the subset of the dual of $E'$ consisting of functionals which are continuous with respect to the $w^*$-topology of $E'$ is equal to the set of of the evaluation functionals.

Comment: Yep, and you're welcome.